# Test endpoint with custom HTTP method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http

I am creating HTTP tests for an existing laravel application as described [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests). The tests look something like this:

```
public function testSomething() 
{
    $this->get('/something')->assertOk();
}
```

The app has some endpoints that use the HTTP SEARCH method, declared like this:

```
Route::addRoute('SEARCH', '', 'SomeController@index');
```

However, the test class doesn't have a `search('/something')` method.

Is there any way to test a route with custom HTTP methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel implement shortcut method for the most used http verb but not all. So if you look closer at the  `$this->get('...')` it's implemented like that:
In `\Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Concerns\MakesHttpRequests`

```
     public function get($uri, array $headers = [])
        {
            $server = $this->transformHeadersToServerVars($headers);
            $cookies = $this->prepareCookiesForRequest();
    
            return $this->call('GET', $uri, [], $cookies, [], $server);
        }
```

So for your use case, you can call

```
$this->call('SEARCH', '/something', [], $cookies, [], $server)->assertOk();
```